# Windows 10 - Metro/Windows Store App - Start as administrator on start up

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-store-app, ditto

I'm using a program called `Ditto` as a clipboard manager. It works really well for everything except applications running as administrators. I then get the following error:

[image]

```
The requested operation requires elevation.
```

To bypass this I can close Ditto and select `Run as administrator` and everything works fine. However since it is a Windows Store app I can't select properties and the folder `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps` is locked and the current owner is set to `TrustedInstaller`. How can I set a Windows Store App to always start as administrator?

**Update:**

Since people are saying it is impossible to select `Run as administrator`. The installed application:

[image]

Search for Ditto in the start menu, right click and select `Run as administrator`.

[image]

Comment: "I can close Ditto and select Run as administrator" How exactly are you doing this?

Comment: @DavidPostill Install, search and right click. See update

Comment: @FleetCommand See update, are you even running Windows 10? I get it in Visual Studio 2017 running as Administrator.

Comment: @Ogglas There is no "Run as administrator" command here. Just "Unpin from Start", "Pin to taskbar" and "Uninstall".

Comment: What are you doing what in Visual Studio 2017 that generates this error message?

Comment: I'm pasting a value from Ditto @FleetCommand

Comment: I believe the reason your able to launch dito-cp as an administrator is unique it shouldn't be possible to launch an actual UEP as an Administrator

Comment: @Ramhound Clean installation of Windows 10 using the media creation tool, installed yesterday:  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Comment: "UEP" was suppose to be "UWP application" and I suspect the reason you are able to elevate the permissions is because the applicatin that was published was converted by Project Centennial.  I would have to look at the source for "ditto-cp" to confirm.  Possible other reasons might also exist, but I have never seen a UWP application myself, that I was able to elevate the permissions for (it should not be required)

Comment: @Ramhound If what you say was right, I should have been able to run it as admin too. I can't.

Answer (score 0):

### Use elevated startup.

1. Create your own elevated autoexec.bat file, e.g.

   ```
   C:\Tools\autoexec-elevated.bat
   ```

   Put all applications you wish to run elevated on startup (including Ditto*) inside it.
2. Using Task Scheduler, add a scheduled task to run this file. Set up its properties like:

   - **General** tab:

     - **Run with highest privileges**: checked
   - **Trigger** tab:

     - **Begin the task**: **At log on**
     - **Delay task for**: **30 seconds**   (...to mitigate initial high system load)
     - **Enabled**: checked
   - **Actions** tab:

     - **Start a program:** `C:\Tools\autoexec-elevated.bat`

*) EDIT: Modern UI Apps (previously known as Metro Apps) can be open from the command line only by [using specific command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26244759/opening-a-file-in-a-metro-app-from-command-line). For example, to open Reader, use the following command line (applies also to batch file):

```
explorer shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.Reader_8wekyb3d8bbwe!Microsoft.Reader
```

Similarly, you will need to find the correct string for Ditto.

Comment: I am very sorry to be downvoting such a well-written answer but the cold hard fact is: Windows Store apps cannot be invoked from within a batch file. Sorry.

Comment: @FleetCommand: thank you for letting me know. I edited the answer to include way of running Windows Store apps from the command line. The example shown in the answer worked nicely for me, including running it from a batch file.

Comment: Downvote rescinded! Pleasure is all mine. Of course, it is my belief that Windows Store apps will refuse to run with admin privileges altogether, but we are already dealing with a person who has "Run as Administrator" in his context menu.

Comment: @FleetCommand - I tested launching the above command line opening Reader app "As administrator" and it worked nicely.

Comment: Do you have admin privileges? (Or is it running without any exotic privileges?)

Comment: @FleetCommand – to test the entire launch process, I put the above command line into a batch file, then set up a scheduled task with administrative privileges to run that batch file. At given time, the Reader Windows Store app was launched with administrative privileges, without UAC prompt.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55031/discussion-between-miroxlav-and-fleet-command).

Answer (score 0):

Finally it seems they handled this problem in version 3.21.223.0 (12-22-2017):

"Fixed issue with pasting into admin app from a low privilege user"